# Remove part of form when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a form that will hide and show some parts of the form. It working correctly in some tries. But when the user chooses and checks an option with class **badCheckbox** which is showing **badField** subsequently then user checks option without class **badCheckbox** which should showing 'goodField' than 'badField' is not hiding and still is shown.

And when a user tries to check options separately all work correctly only in upper mentioned case.

Is there any way to do it?

```js
//Script to hide and show div
$('.badCheckbox').change(function() {
  let checked = 0;
  $('.badCheckbox').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      checked += 1;
    }
  });
  if (checked != 0) {
    $('#badField').show();
    $('#goodField').hide();
  } else {
    $('#badField').hide();
    $('#goodField').show();
  }
});

//script to check only one of three
$(".oneChecked").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked badCheckbox" />
<input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked badCheckbox" />
<input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked" />

<div id="badField" style="display:none;">
  <p>:((</p>
  <input type="submit" />
</div>

<div id="goodField">
  <p>NICE!!!</p>
  <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a radio? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: This problem is the same on type checkbox and radio :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might help to use `:checked` in your selector. This way you can target elements that are checked versus not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following improvements.

```js
$(function() {
  function checkStuff(checked) {
    if (checked) {
      $('#badField').show();
      $('#goodField').hide();
    } else {
      $('#badField').hide();
      $('#goodField').show();
    }
  }

  //script to check only one of three
  $(".boxes").on('change', ".oneChecked", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(".boxes input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
      checkStuff($(this).is(".badCheckbox"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked badCheckbox" />
  <input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked badCheckbox" />
  <input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked" />
</div>

<div id="badField" style="display:none;">
  <p>:((</p>
  <input type="submit" />
</div>

<div id="goodField">
  <p>NICE!!!</p>
  <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a short version

```js
$('#checks').on('change', 'input[name="checkin"]', function (){

    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('#checks .oneChecked:checked').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#checks .oneChecked:checked').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }

    if( $('#checks .badCheckbox:checked').is(':checked') ){
        $('#badField').show();
        $('#goodField').hide();
    } else {
        $('#badField').hide();
        $('#goodField').show();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="checks">
    <input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked badCheckbox"/>
    <input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked badCheckbox"/>
    <input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="oneChecked"/>
</div>
    <div id="badField" style="display:none;">
      <p>:((</p>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </div>

    <div id="goodField">
      <p>NICE!!!</p>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: I forgott to add <div id="checks"></div> :) here, now it work :)

Answer (score 0):

it's because you don't have an event when user click and the third checkbox.

Your function to show/hide message work when there are an update (change) on an input with the class `.badCheckbox` but when you click on the third (where doesn't have the class) your function is not called.

I think you should have a class on all your checkbox and use it in your function who lister the change.

Something like this :

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
    let checked = 0;
    $('.badCheckbox').each(function() {
      // ...
});
```

And your html

```
<input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="checkbox oneChecked badCheckbox"/>
<input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="checkbox oneChecked badCheckbox"/>
<input name="checkin" type="checkbox" class="checkbox oneChecked"/>
```

There is a lot of optimization that can be done to improve your code, like using the radio to remove your `oneChecked` function or printing the right message when the checkbox is checked instead of using show/hide two `div` but i think you should see it in the future

I hope this can help you and welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

First of all, obviously your checkboxes have to act like radios. As I understand, that is what you want to do. So, I modifyed your script a little bit to make checkboses to act as they are radio inputs, and in the same time to show/hide paragraph, depending on if clicked element has class badCheckbox and it's state (checkd or not). Here is the result:

```
//Script to hide and show div
$('.oneChecked').click( (everyOne) => {
   //handles click (and change) on every element with class oneChecked
   //they all has it in your example
   $('.oneChecked').each( (ind, currentOne) => {
     //iterate to all elements with class oneChecked
     //and compare if matches clicked one
     if ( !$(currentOne).is($(everyOne.target)) ) {
       //other instance, not clisked one, so clear it
       //to simulate behaviour of radio input
       $(currentOne).prop('checked', false);
     }
   });

   //checks if clicked element is bad or not and show/hide your p
   if ($(everyOne.target).hasClass('badCheckbox') && $(everyOne.target).prop('checked')){
     console.log('b-s/h');
        $('#badField').show();
        $('#goodField').hide();
     } else {
     console.log('s/b-h');
       $('#badField').hide();
       $('#goodField').show();
   }

});
```

Here is an workign example in CodePen: https://codepen.io/kalatchev/pen/gOpJBOv